# Prove that $\mathbb{R}_{\neq0}$ is not a real vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Assume a set of $\mathbb{R}_{\neq0}=\{a \in \mathbb{R} \mid a \neq 0\}$, where addition of elements in $\mathbb{R}_{\neq0}$ is the product in scalar $ab$. Prove that this is not a real vector space.

I have made the assumption that the scalar product for the elements is the power of it, $a^k$, $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq0}$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

And then I went through all the definitions for vector space and this vector space fulfills it. I've seen a rule somewhere that says if $ka=kb$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{\neq0}$ and $k\in\mathbb{R}$, then $a=b$. If I put $k=2$ and $a=1$, $b=-1$ then it doesn't satisfy the rule, but is that rule even correct?

Comment: Well, how'd you define $\;0\cdot a\;,\;\;0$ the scalar, $\;a\in\Bbb R^*\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio As I've assumed scalar product as the power of it, so $0 \cdot a=a^0=1$, where $1$ is the identity element in this supposedly vector space.

Comment: Your scalar product is not well defined. What is $(-1)^{1/2}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make $V=\mathbb R_{\ne0}$ a vector space, we need two operations: An addition $\oplus\colon V\times V\to V$, which we are given by the problem statement: $v\oplus w=v\cdot w$; and a scalar multiplication $\odot\colon \mathbb R\times V\to V$, which we are not given. However, we can see that no matter how we try to define $\odot$, we run into trouble. Let us first study $\oplus$ further: $V$ should be an abelian group und $\oplus$ and we easily check that it indeed is. The neutral element is $1$ and hence we need $x\odot 1=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Apart from that we have $2\odot(-1)=(1+1)\odot(-1)=(1\odot(-1))\oplus(1\odot(-1))=(-1)\oplus(-1)=1$, but then $-1=1\odot(- 1)=(\frac12\cdot 2)\odot(-1)=\frac12\odot(2\odot(-1))=\frac12\odot 1=1$, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! I have never thought that I can check even before defining the operations.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I didn't see that part of the scalar multiplication. Ok.

But then we might have some serious problems: what is

$$\;\frac12\cdot (-1):=(-1)^{1/2}=\sqrt{-1}\;\;\text{within}\;\;\Bbb R^*\;?$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so $\sqrt{-1}$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{R}_{\neq0}$, so it cannot be considered as a vector space. But the thing is I made that assumption for scalar multiplication, the question only defined the addition so I'd probably also need to show contradiction for other operations? I'm not too sure if I'm on the right track :S

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Here is a proof of the rule you cited. $k\in\mathbb R$ so its inverse $k^{-1}\in\mathbb R$ is also a scalar. Left multiply by $k^{-1}$ on both sides to get $k^{-1}(ka)=k^{-1}(kb)$. By "associativity" we have that $(k^{-1}k)a=(k^{-1}k)b$ and by definition $1a=1b$. Then since $1$ is an "identity" for scalar multiplication, this gives $a=b$.

Since you showed an example for which this rule fails, there should be some step in the proof which is not justified for this space. Which is it?